$\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}+6\ge4\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)$
Given that $a$, $b$ are positive real numbers, prove that:
$\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}+6\ge4\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)$
To do this question, first I applied AM-GM to the terms as follows:
$\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}} \ge 2$, and $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a} \ge 2$
But I have realised that while this is true, I cannot move terms to one side without proving which of $\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}$ or $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$ is greater.
Can someone provide assistance for another way to do this question?

name $w = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a} .$   You have concluded that $w \geq 2.$  Next, what is $w^2  ;  ; ? ; ; $

^2 is ≥ 4, ...

Yeah but also, write $w^2$ in terms of $a$ and $b...$

and write the original inequality in terms of $w$ and $w^2$

Actually, there is no need to use the AM-GM inequality

The simple way is to expand $(a/b+b/a-2)^2\geq0$ and rearrange/

Hint: $$\left[\left(\frac{a} {b} + \frac{b}{a}\right) - 2 \right]^2$$
is a square...

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+6-4\frac{a}{b}-4\frac{b}{a}=\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-2\right)^2\ge 0$$
